# Apache Camel asynchronus two way messaging

Tags: java, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

After long time of research i still have no acceptable solution for my purposes.

**Intend**:
I'm trying to have multiple Endpoints/Components which are generating exchanges with proprietary content. (*1st row 1st col in picture*)

Thus exchanges should be normalized by a normalizer/translator (*1st row 2nd col in picture*)

Finally this normalized data should be processed. (Saved to database, did some aggregations, calculating some results).

After a result is generated, a completely new exchange should be generated and populated to routes, where this processor is located in the "from" statement. (*2nd Row*) -> Data should be translated to proprietary data -> send to endpoint

**Questions & Preliminary Findings**

- A Processor could not be located in the "from" statement directly. I
  only  found some workarounds in the manner " from
  (direct:somemessages)" which is created in the processor by
  to(direct:somemessages)
- The Processor could be programmes as a Component with an endpoint.
  And the asynchronus messages could be published with the
  corresponding Consumer

**Example Route Ingoing (*1st row*)**

```
  <route id="bar">
        <from uri="mqtt"/>
        <to uri="TranslateMQTT2MyModel"/>
        <to uri="ProcessData"/>
    </route>
```

**Example Route Outgoing (i would like to have) (*2nd row*)**

```
  <route id="out">
        <from uri="ProcessData"/>
        <to uri="TranslateMyModel2MQTT"/>
        <to uri="mqtt"/>
    </route>
```

So how I can achieve my purposes? Is one of my two outcomes a good solution?

[Example of schematic workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZXfT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a "ProcessData" component that is a consumer, but I don't think you need to do that.

I think you can use the asynchronous capability of the SEDA component, so I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
<route id="bar">
    <from uri="mqtt"/>
    <to uri="TranslateMQTT2MyModel"/>
    <to uri="seda:processAndReply"/>
</route>

<route id="out">
    <from uri="seda:processAndReply" />
    <to uri="ProcessData"/>
    <to uri="TranslateMyModel2MQTT"/>
    <to uri="mqtt"/>
</route>
```

The SEDA component works similarly to direct as you described, but direct is synchronous and SEDA is asynchronous. (Also note the VM and Direct-VM components if you need to link between Camel Contexts with the same JVM).